# react-select default value not working for multiple selects

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I am using `react-select` for displaying a list of service, I want to display the first two services as default services but the defaultValue is not working for me. 
 I am using react-select version `4.3.1`.

```
const [selectedservices, setselectedservices] = useState([]);
const services = [
{id: 70, value: 'today', label: 'today'},
{id: -1, value: 'All Services', label: 'All Services'}
{id: 81, value: 'plan', label: 'plan'},
{id: 79, value: 'time', label: 'time'},
{id: 78, value: 'recurring', label: 'recurring'},
{id: 76, value: 'jj (Copy)', label: 'jj (Copy)'},
{id: 75, value: 'final maybe', label: 'final maybe'}
];

 const handleService = (e) => {
    const a = [];
    e.map((i) => a.push(i.id));
    setselectedservices([...a]);
  };

<Select
   isMulti
   placeholder="All Services"
   onChange={(e) => handleService(e)}
   defaultValue={services.slice(0, 2).map((i) => i)}
   options={services}
   className="basic-multi-select"
   classNamePrefix="select"
/>
```

The value field is working but the defaultValue field is not working, **how do i set a default value for react-select?**

Comment: What errors are you getting? How is the UI show to you?

Comment: it is not displying any default value at all, no errors

Comment: You could check the codesanbox on my answer to have a reference, It's working well there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**It should be working well, please check for errors or your setup from other places**

If `services` comes from BE, you would rather use `value` than `defaultValue`

Here is a working example generated from your code:

[image: Edit pedantic-tesla-7iz7n]

Comment: This code is working fine, but actually the `services` is loaded from the database, if i hard code services the defaultValue is displayed but when it is loaded from the database it is not shown.

Comment: any suggestion to this?

Comment: Then you could use a direct value for it, not defaultValue. I've updated the code inside attached codesanbox, Please take a look